# memory handling in c# windows application

Tags: c#, winforms, memory-management

I've a windows forms application. When i try to run this application it is increasing mem Usage continuously. How can i control this?

just my application contains only 10 to 15 database calls.

*Code from comment to answer (there's no context though):*

```
Label lbl = new Label();
lbl.Text = "my data label";
lblrss.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8F,
                                      System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold,
                                      System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point,
                                      ((byte)(0)));
lblrss.Click += new EventHandler(llrss_Click);
mytbl.Controls.Add(lbl);
```

this is my code plz check it

thank you,
Nagu

Comment: This is a very abstract question. There could be a ton of reasons that can cause memory to spike such as not disposing unmanaged resources,not unhooking event handlers, working with large XML data are a few common causes

Comment: I've posted your code in the comment below as an edit to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure you are closing the Reader and Database Connection
2. If you are adding event handlers to the dynamic data items, remove the event listeners before binding next time.

Without code, I can only give you these two points to focus.

Comment: Label lbl = new Label();
                    lbl.Text = "my data label";
                    lblrss.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
                    lblrss.Click += new EventHandler(llrss_Click);
                    mytbl.Controls.Add(lbl);
                    

this is my code plz check it

Comment: you should remove event handler of your lblrss.Click if its set everytime